# AngularJS Service fetches Json but wont show it in browser or in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have been struggled with this for quite sometime, though I am fairly new to angularjs but I cant figure out whats going on wrong here, coz console logs nothing as error.

I have reproduced the issue at a plunk. What I want is the value and Reps logged. Everything seems to be okay but I have a feeling that I am not Binding Services and Controllers properly(Maybe)

Any help is hugely appreciated..

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kqvm2bTNNm0wfAXMpcKg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$http returns a promise, use then() to set the items using the items property of your response.

`testAPP.controller('stackCtrl', function stackCtrl($scope, userQuestionService) {
  $scope.name = "This is a  Heading";
  userQuestionService.getUserQuestions().then(function(response){
    $scope.items = response.items; 
  });
});`

I had this as the test output

`Reps is {{item.a_id}} and Value is {{item.owner.reputation}}`

Comment: thanks buddy, I am just stretching this here, If I have to fetch my hellojson from a cross domain server, what changes do I need to make?

Comment: @Mike jsonp would be the way to go I believe